# Decrypted values not displaying properly

Tags: php, encryption

I am encrypting the values and sending an encrypted value on another page with the help of URL and there I am decrypting values but decrypted value is not displaying properly. I am getting output like 
\j3�B��9[rΫ�m�N�B~=��:�nc.�

Would you help me in this?

**Index.php**

```
$input =5;
$encrypted = encryptIt( $input );
echo $encrypted;
function encryptIt( $q ) {
    $cryptKey  = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
    $qEncoded      = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), $q, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ) );
    return( $qEncoded );
}

echo "<a href='decry.php?user_id=$encrypted'>Click here</a>";
```

**decry.php**

```
$id=$_GET['user_id'];
$decrypted = decryptIt( $id );
echo $decrypted;
function decryptIt( $q ) {
    $cryptKey  = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
    $qDecoded      = rtrim( mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), base64_decode( $q ), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ), "\0");
    return( $qDecoded );
}
```

Comment: **WARNING:** `mcrypt_encrypt` is deprecated in PHP7.1

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.RiggsFolly. Is there any other way? because I am able to decrypt the value on the same page but not on another page

Comment: The encrypt and decrypt work fine so it must be something to do with how you pass the values about on the querystring

Comment: If something's worth encrypting, it doesn't belong in a URL ... you should rethink what you're doing.

Comment: The mcrypt extension has been abandonware for nearly a decade now, and was also fairly complex to use. It has therefore been deprecated in favour of OpenSSL, where it will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2.

Comment: It is probably because the last character is an `=` and an `=` on the querystring is being chopped off  as it means something else to PHP

Comment: Use `urlencode()` before using it as parameter in an url.

Comment: Thanks for your information Mr.RiggsFolly. What I am achieving is My currently URl is <a href="demo.php?user_id=5> and I have to display like <a href="demo.php user_id="QWlZ1zIU9bYS0Xmk9ieZPSfegxn+Zm2BAh0RSoKGuhU=">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RiggsFolly said using `urlencode()`. 
As I tried it with different numbers it worked fine for some. While others had the problem stated above (I guess it is down the `=` appearing) but once I added `urlencode()` that fixed it!

```
$input =5;
$encrypted = encryptIt( $input );
echo $encrypted;
function encryptIt( $q ) {
    $cryptKey  = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
    $qEncoded      = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), $q, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ) );
    return( $qEncoded );
}

echo "<a href='decry.php?user_id=".urlencode($encrypted)."'>Click here</a>";
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Razentic. It is working for me but Is there any Issue will get in future?

Comment: I don't think there will be any issues in the future (I made a quick edit as reading it back it did not make that much sense!).

Comment: Thanks for your help Mr.Razentic.